# How can we find Rotor position of 5AMA400 motor?

Tags: motor, synchronous

I am a technical teacher at high school. All of the components we produce are handmade.  We've igbt inverter for a three phase our Wound-rotor synchronous motor control project (Renault Fluence ZE 5AMA400 400V 90hp) with my student. How can we find Rotor position of 5AMA400 motor?  https://youtu.be/NbTXQtmV1vE

Comment: Use a rotary position encoder.